# Error Code: 1109. Unknown table 'takes' in delete statement

Tags: mysql, sql-delete

```
delete takes
    from takes as T inner join course as C on T.course_id = C.course_id
    where title like '%database%';
```

I have two tables takes(ID, course_id, semester, grade) and course(course_id, title, dept_name, credits). Whenever a certain word appears in "title", remove the row in takes that has the same course_id. This is the code I have for that, but it returns the 1109 error. Anyone know why?

> Error Code: 1109. Unknown table 'takes' in MULTI DELETE in this code?

Comment: it's `delete from TABLE`, not `delete whatever from TABLE`.

Comment: Can you give me in context example? I removed the "takes" after the delete, and it resulted in an error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe the reason you're receiving an error would be that you're assigning an alias `t` to table `takes`, but you forgot to alter your delete statement at the beginning, so it actually complains about not having table `takes` in the delete statements (it's `t`) in your query.

Try this:

```
delete t
    from takes as t
    inner join course as c on t.course_id = c.course_id
    where title like '%database%';
```

Comment: I tried and got the error Error Code: 1175. You are using safe update mode and you tried to update a table without a WHERE that uses a KEY column To disable safe mode, toggle the option in Preferences -> SQL Editor and reconnect.